# debug c# without unity3d editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to devlop c# part of unity3d game without installing unity3d on my work computer. I can build it with dll's. But i can't run this project outside unity3d environment.
Is there any solutions for such way of development?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html

Comment: I'd like to devlop c# part of unity3d game **without installing unity3d** on my work computer. Please, read before answering.

Comment: what is stopping you then? if you don't need to reference the unity3d engine then just create a new dll library project in C# in Visual Studio... if you do need the engine look up how to get just the engine PIAs rather than the entire development platfom..

Comment: You can't. In order to debug the code you need to run the project and you need the Unity editor and your system specific playback engine to do that.

Comment: Remember a version of unity is installable through vs, if you have that then you can argue with work any “updqtes” are keeping it safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such solutions.

First of all unityengine.dll is basically a wrapper around native objects which are maintained by the engine. It needs unity to work properly.

The second thing is the engine design. 
There are two approaches for game engines - the loop based and callback based.

The loop based design expects your code to have a method, similiar to "main" except that the engine call's it on every frame. The example is XNA.

Unity however uses the callback based approach. It invokes the callbacks you provide and the order in which they are called is determined solely by the engine.

So even if you find/make an assembly that mimics unityengine API, and manage launch your code you still can't guarantee that it will behave the same way in the game, since the order of oxecution will most likely be different.

Answer (score 1):

if its a unity based project, then it probably depends on the unity engine resources to run and therefore you need to use unity to run an unbuilt version.